# Trying to make substrings from a string in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string `aaaaabbbbbccccc` I have a dictionary that has certain rules

```
Dictionary<string, string> rules = new Dictionary<string, string>();
rules.Add("abc", "aab");
rules.Add("ac", "ba");
rules.Add("cb", "cc");
```

This means if string has `abc` it will be replaced with `aab` but string doesn't have any rules that match. So, I am creating a new string out of the old string based on these rules. For instance, if I rearrange the old string to `abcabcabcabcabc` then rule can be applied. But I am stuck at rearranging. I tried using `IndexOf` and `Remove` functions but I didn't get the positive output. This is my code

```
string s;
s = "aaaaabbbbbccccc";
string newString = "";
int ia, ib, ic;
//Formulating rule 1
if (s.Contains("a") && s.Contains("b") && s.Contains("c"))
{
    ia = s.IndexOf("a");
    ib = s.IndexOf("b");
    ic = s.IndexOf("c");

    if (ia < ib && ib < ic)
    {
        newString += "abc";
        s.Remove(ia, 1);
        s.Remove(ib, 1);
        s.Remove(ic, 1);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("New String " + newString);
Console.WriteLine("Old String " + s);
```

I am getting

```
New String abc
Old String aaaaabbbbbccccc  //Which is wrong.
```

Can anyone help what I am doing wrong or is there any better way?

Comment: You need to assign the result of the Remove to s. `s = s.Remove(ia, 1);`

Comment: In your explanation, you say that `aaaaabbbbbccccc` does not match any rule (e.g. the "abc" rule). However, in your code, you are not checking if it contains "abc", but rather that it contain "a" and "b" and "c", not necessarily as a single chunk. You're contradicting yourself, which one is correct? Does the rule check for the _exact_ string, or does it check for all characters separately?

Comment: So if you have `"aabbcc"` you want `"abcabc"` right ? What if you have `"aaabbcc"`? What happends to this extra `a` ? Can you be really explicit on what is the input few exemple and whats the output? and whats the process . Because your attempt is at least confusing.

Comment: @DragandDrop hi, if it is extra `a` it is appended at the end of the new string.

Comment: There is a lot going wrong... first of all, you evaluate your string _once_, so you would not replace all available a, b and c's. Secondly,`indexOf` can return -1, which can lead to strange behaviour in your code. Thirdly, the `Remove`s should be assigned to s, and if you execute them in this order, you are removing the wrong items after the first remove. Try _debugging_ to see what your code is actually doing to get an idea of why this doesn't work at all.

Comment: Before debugging, take 2 minute and write down the requirement then apply them to at least 2 strings. A valid simple one "aabbcc". An every wrong case "aabbccac". Then [edit] all this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Your explanation does not match your code.

In your explanation, you say that `aaaaabbbbbccccc` does not match any rule (e.g. the "abc" rule). However, in your code, you are not checking if it contains "abc", but rather that it contain "a" and "b" and "c", not necessarily as a single chunk:

```
if (s.Contains("a") && s.Contains("b") && s.Contains("c"))
```

This is an important difference:

- `aaaaabbbbbccccc` **does not** contain `abc` (rule does not apply)
- `aaaaabbbbbccccc` **does** contain `a`, `b` and `c` (rule does apply)

You're contradicting yourself. Which is correct here, the code or your explanation? Does the rule check for the exact string, or does it check for all characters separately?

---

### **Awkward string manipulation.**

Based on your code; I infer that you're not experienced with some very common string operations (no offense intended). Unless you contradict me, I'm going to assume that your explanation is correct and your code is not.

**Checking if a string contains a substring:**

As I explained previously, there is an important difference between checking is a string contains a substring:

```
s.Contains("abc") //1
```

and checking if a string contains each individual character of a substring:

```
s.Contains("a") && s.Contains("b") && s.Contains("c") //2
```

As a more practical example; does my username (Flater) contain the substring "Fertla"?

- If you use the logic in `//1`, the answer is **no**.
- If you use the logic in `//2`, the answer is **yes**.

Based on your explanation, you should be using `//1`

**Replacing a string**:

> This means if string has `abc` it will be replaced with `aab`

There is a very simple method for this:

```
s.Replace("abc", "aab");
```

Some examples:

> - `abcdef` becomes `aabdef`
> - `abcabcabc` becomes `aabaabaab` (it replaces **all** occurrences)
> - `uvwxyz` becomes `uvwxyz` (if it doesn't occur, nothing gets replaced)

Take note of the second and third bullet point.

2. `String.Replace()` will replace **all** occurrences, in case the substring occurs more than once. Based on your explanation, I assume this is what you want (if it's possible for a substring to occur more than once, to begin with).
3. If the substring is not found, `String.Replace()` will give you the same output as its input. Nothing will be changed. This means that you can execute your rule on your string without needing to check if the substring exists:

   - If it does exist, then your value will be replaced; just like you want it to happen.
   - If it does not exist, then nothing will happen; which is also what you want to happen.

---

### You can dramatically simplify your code!

Create your dictionary;

```
Dictionary<string, string> rules = new Dictionary<string, string>();

rules.Add("abc", "aab");
rules.Add("ac", "ba");
rules.Add("cb", "cc");
```

Define your string:

```
string s = "aaaaaaabbbbbbccccccc";
```

And the rest is easy enough:

```
foreach(var rule in rules)
{
    s = s.Replace(rule.Key, rule.Value);
}
```

This will try to perform a replace for every rule that you've defined. If it finds rules that are applicable; then it will replace the values.

> **Note**
>   This code assumes that your replace values do not collide. If you do want to avoid collisions, you will have to check if substrings of all defined rules exist (`Contains()`) **before** actually replacing a value.

Comment: I got you mate, I have done this. But, my problem is the second part of this thing. That if there aren't any matching rules, then it will create strings out of the old string, for instance, if my old string is `aaabbcc` and it has no matching rules, then it can be rearranged to as `abcabca`.

Comment: @HaritiDesai: You need to be **way** more specific. are you trying to literally test every permutation of the string's characters? How do you ensure that you test "abcabc" before you test "aabcbc" (assume you started from "aabbcc" which gave no matches)? What happens if a permutation yields one match? Do you stop looking for other permutations? This is a very vague problem description.

Comment: @HaritiDesai: I get the suspicion that we're dealing with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Your intended logic seems contrived and it's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve overall. I would suggest reworking your question to include the actual goal you're trying to achieve; and a specific explanation of the behavior you're looking for (because you never even mentioned the string permutation, which is now suddenly relevant after reading my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a really hard time understanding you requierment, but here is a solution may you tell me if this is even close to what you want?

```
private static string  WeirdArrangement (string input)
{
    //string input = "aabbcc[aczç_eyvur]";

    string validChars = "abc";
    string pattern = "abc";     // Must be a composition of  all valid char

    var invalidChars = input.Where(c => !validChars.Contains(c));
    var validOccurences = input.Where(c => validChars.Contains(c))
                                .GroupBy(c => c)
                                .Select(c => new { Char = c.Key, Count = c.Count() });

    var minPattern = validOccurences.Min(o => o.Count);


    // Build time
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        //new StringBuilder(pattern.Length * minPattern + invalidChars.Count() + leftoverCount);

    // X time partern
    for (int i = 0; i < minPattern; i++) builder.Append(pattern);

    //Rest of the validOccurences
    foreach (var charOccurency in validOccurences)
    {
        for (int i = minPattern; i < charOccurency.Count; i++) builder.Append(charOccurency.Char);
    }

    //Invalid char
    foreach (var invalidChar in invalidChars)
    {
        builder.Append(invalidChar);
    };

    return builder.ToString();
}
```